# How to create an access token without a password for a user in the identityServer4, to access another api from api

Tags: .net-core, identityserver4

There are 2 APIs, external and internal:

- the external API uses resource ownership token authorization
- the internal API uses just a login/password.

There was a task to forward a call from an external API to an internal one. An external user with his token requests an external resource, which in turn calls the internal API with the internal user's token simply by HttpClient with the jwt-token.

I see a problem. I can't sign in internal user and get `HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token")` because I already have another user logged in.

Any ideas?